# Methodology and basis set for study in UV-Vis

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am currently working with a system of 30 atoms of a organic molecule. I need to make a study related to determine the UV-Vis graphic as precisely as possible.

I am using DFT method. However, I am having trouble to find a methodology and basis set to obtain a proper result of the experiment.

Does anybody know what methodology and basis set I should use?

P.S: I have already tried B3LYP with 6-31G(d), 6-31G(d,p) and 6-311++G(2d, 2p) in sequence but the results weren't good.

Comment: Simple functionals and Pople-style basis sets are notoriously bad for UV/Vis.  DFT and TD-DFT in general aren't that great, unfortunately, AFAIK, but there may be some decent options. I'll ping an expert in chat to come take a look.

Comment: Ooof. Said expert is in the middle of an international move, and not reachable in chat at the moment.

Comment: Look for benchmark papers from Denis Jacquemin.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about "weren't good." There are many benchmarks, but results are generally accurate to ~0.2 eV. Are you including a solvent model, for example?

Comment: The other question is whether you're just trying to get low-lying $\pi-\pi^*$ transitions or you want CT or Rydberg states.

Comment: If you can provide more details, it would be helpful.